# Angular ServiceWorker: caching multiple HTTP Requests

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I try to cache http-requests in my service worker. But I'm only able to cache the last request to a specific URL.

From my understanding it should cache the last 100 responses (maxSize: 100). The Http-Request has all the time the same URL (e.g.: ./player/example) and the Http-Header is different for all requests.

Here ist my `ngsw-conf`:

```
"dataGroups": [{
    "name": "api-freshness",
    "urls": [
        "/player/**"
    ],
    "cacheConfig": {
        "maxSize": 100,
        "maxAge": "1h",
        "timeout": "3s",
        "strategy": "freshness"
    }
}]
```

Comment: This seems to be quite correct. As you probably cache your responses like `cache.put(request, response)` (only GET requests, mind you).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

If the URL is the exact same, only the last response gets cached. So I had to switch my backend to a REST API (every REST-Call is slightly different now). Now everything works fine and every request gets cached as expected. :-)